# Flask file upload returns error 405 method not allowed

Tags: python-3.x, flask, cpanel, http-status-code-405

The code below is endpoint used to upload images for a transaction in site am working but for some reason it keeps returning 405 error when a file attached to the request but works like it should when it isnt. So the code works locally and another server(used a similar code for site) but not on control server.

```
@bp.route("/transaction/<int:transaction_id>/image", methods=['PUT'])
def upload_image_ex(transaction_id):
    transaction = Transaction.query.get(transaction_id)
    
    if not transaction:
        return jsonify(status='failed', message='Transaction Not Found!')
    if transaction.status != 0:
        return jsonify(status='failed', message='Transaction No Longer Pending!')

    if 'images[]' not in request.files:
        return jsonify(status='failed', message='No image uploaded!')

    files = request.files.getlist('images[]')

    for file in files:
        print("dayer")
        unique_filename = str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.' + \
            file.filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower()
        print("dayer")
        file.save(os.path.join(Config.POST_UPLOAD_FOLDER, unique_filename))
        print("dayer")
        save_image(
            unique_filename,
            file,
            Config.POST_UPLOAD_FOLDER,
            Config.BANNER_SIZE,
            isByte=False
        )

        img = TransactionImage()
        img.img = unique_filename
        img.transaction_id = transaction_id
        db.session.add(img)

    db.session.commit()

    return jsonify(
        status='success',
        message='Transaction Image Uploaded',
        data=TransactionSchema().dump(transaction)
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Check your frontend call, if the method is `PUT`.
2. Check the reverse proxy like `nginx` on your server if it changed the location or methods of the call.
3. Try add `POST`, `PATCH` ... methods into your route to address the problem. `@bp.route("/transaction/<int:transaction_id>/image", methods=['PUT', 'POST', 'PATCH'])`